# jQuery concatenate selector and text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create an element with some text after it to add to a container element.

Say I have:

```
$('<span/>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close') + ' ' + item.name
```

and I want that to work; is there a way?

I know I can use `add()` like so:

```
$('<span/>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close').add(
    $('<span/>').html(' ' + item.name)
)
```

But can I do it without the extra selector?

Comment: You can, if you use strings, but what's wrong with calling jQuery twice to create two elements

Comment: @adeneo code overhead, HTML element overhead, and when using in complex UI massive HTML overhead

Comment: But you're **creating** elements, not getting them, so it shouldn't matter, the browser has to create those elements anyway, there's no overhead, if you need to create two elements there are no shortcuts, you have to create two elements. If you really want to optimize, you'd use `createElement` instead, but it still .... wait for it ... creates two elements, or you clone the first element, but that still creates two elements.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ...in words

Comment: @charlietfl add a jQuery selector and a text node together

Comment: There are no text nodes here, just two spans ?

Comment: @adeneo the first line which I want to work and ask if it can contains a span and a text node

Comment: well that is even more confusing than the code description

Comment: you can do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fL51amgc/) ?

Comment: @adeneo no the CSS output from that is... Broken due to the class of glyphicon

Comment: Oh right, you really want a span, followed by a span, like `<span class="icon"></span><span>text</span>`. What you're doing is just fine for that, there's no overhead

Comment: @adeneo what I really want is a span followed by some text

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like it will work: '$('<span/>').html(item.name).addClass('glyphicon')

Comment: @pivanchy ok, I have added bootstrap tags so hopefully that should be more clear as to why that won't work

Comment: Something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/fL51amgc/1/, but it still creates a node for the text (a textnode), same thing really

Comment: @adeneo that inserts the text into the span, check the source for the run

Comment: just append your text to the parent

Comment: @charlietfl the expected results, as I have said in the code and in the response when you asked, is to concatenate a span node and a text node

Comment: @charlietfl that is one option, not a very elegant one but it is one,

Comment: I really don't get the point, but -> **https://jsfiddle.net/fL51amgc/3/**

Comment: @adeneo so the only way is hacky like that?

Comment: @Sammaye depends where you put this...see solution I updated using chained append

Comment: @charlietfl it does seem as though appending to parent oveer and over is probably the best way, it is a bit hacky  to forceably create a text node. I am surprised since this seems like such a simple and common thing

Comment: not common at all ... norm is to use html

Comment: What you have is fine, really, I don't see why you wouldn't just use a span for the text, there's no performance difference in inserting a textNode in the document. Anyway, if it looks hacky, you could probably use `add` if that makes it less hacky for you, something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/fL51amgc/4/

Comment: @adeneo if you add that as an answer I'll upvote

Comment: It seems both the original code, and the answers, do this fine? *(I would never use `$.parseHTML` just to create a textNode though)*

Comment: @adeneo well, here I am doing a file manager for my CDN (for my company) whereby the file count shown on page could be 500 or more and there could be 10 excess span elements since I repeat this process for a few things so I am dealing with 5000 extra HTML elements, but meh

Comment: @adeneo well, I was looking for another way without using `add()` and making a new selector each time so your answer goes further than the original code

Comment: The problem usually isn't creating many elements, it's how they are inserted into the DOM. Inserting 5000 elements takes milliseconds if they are inserted at once, in for instance a fragment, but it could take minutes if they are all inserted one by one in a loop

Comment: @adeneo well, the JS can take a while this is for internal use, it is actually that Chrome and Firefox actually use memory for how many HTML elements are on page and I have it before now where I have killed tabs by using too much HTML

Comment: @Sammaye creating those text nodes for that reason is just silly. There are lots of ways to make the dom paginated, or other view on demand UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append a text node it could  be done using `append(item.name)` to the parent

```
var $span = $('<span/>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close')
$('.someSelector')
      .append($span) 
      .append(item.name);//will be after span
```

Comment: As mentioned in the last comment if you look on an actual Bootstrap page you will realise the CSS for this is broken, plus this is not what I am asking to do

Comment: well you never provided expected results ... surprising for 26k rep

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`jQuery.parseHTML( data [, context ] [, keepScripts ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parseHTML/#jQuery-parseHTML-data-context-keepScripts)

> **keepScripts** (default: false)
>
> Type: `Boolean`
>
> A `Boolean` indicating whether to include scripts passed in the HTML string

```js
var nodes = $.parseHTML("<span class=glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close>span</span>"
            + " text node"
            , document /* [, keepScripts] default: `false` */); 
$("body").append(nodes)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: nope...we've been down that road... text is after span

Comment: @charlietfl Tried to interpret comments before posting ; `.after()` ?

Comment: The edit is interesting but what if you cannot trust the content? Seems like a huge security hole to me

Comment: @Sammaye _" but what if you cannot trust the content? Seems like a huge security hole to me"_  Could set third parameter to `$.parseHTML()` to `false` to remove `script` elements. See updated post. Though , note, original Question appear to describe `text` node, not `script` elements